# Serializing ArrayList using protobuf-net v2

Tags: protobuf-net

I am a protobuf-net beginner and have just installed v2r470, to be used
in my C#-WinForm application.
I get an `"InvalidOperationException was unhandled" - "No serializer defined for type: System.Object"` when serializing an `ArrayList`.

**Serializable class:**

```
[ProtoContract]
public class ProtoData
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    public ProtoData()
    {
        list.Clear();
        list.Add("Hello");
        list.Add("World");
    }
}
```

**Serialization:**

```
        ProtoData pData = new ProtoData();
        var file = File.Create("protodata.bin");
        Serializer.Serialize<ProtoData>(file, pData);   // <<----- error
```

What's missing here?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, protobuf-net will prefer homogeneous data; in your case you seem to be storing lists; it you make `list` a `List<string>`, then it will *just work*.

protobuf (the format, not protobuf-net specifically) is engineered around an **expected and known** schema; you can't just say "an object" - it wants to know more than that. I protobuf-net I have added various tweaks and trips to make that achievable, but the most appropriate approach would depend on what *exactly* your actual model is trying to do. So far, it is trying to store 2 strings; `List<string>` is the most appropriate way to do that. Like I say, though, there are a few other ways to do similar things with heterogeneous data.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I have nested Arraylists, i.e. ArrayList containing objects with other ArrayLists etc. Serializing using BinaryFormatter works just fine, and I hoped it would in protobuf-net as well.  I will look into the workload to go from ArrayList to List<>

Comment: I should note that the RuntimeTypeModel does allow you to explicitly state the item-type for lists, allowing it to work with ArrayList, but simpy using List-of-T is easier and clearer

Comment: @StefanS note; my comment above; if the objects **are of the same type**, it can work with ArrayList. Is it an ArrayList of ArrayList? or is it an ArrayList of some type that *has* (encapsulates) an ArrayList? (this matters, too)

Comment: I want to serialize an object containing several ArrayLists as well as simple types (int, string etc.). The encapsulated ArrayLists contains objects of different types, each of which also contains ArrayLists and simple types.

Comment: @StefanS "The encapsulated ArrayLists contain objects of different types" - there are ways to do that, but it would require structural changes to the model. protobuf-net is a versatile tool, but it is **not** a direct 1:1 swap-out from BinaryFormatter. By the very nature  of storing less metadata, it needs a way to understand the model more clearly up-front. How much change is acceptable?

Comment: @StefanS why are you using ArrayList anyway? can you narrow down the types you wish to add to your list? can you make all the types an ISomething?

Comment: @wal note that for the purposes of serialization, that wouldn't necessarily be a step forward. Plus, you can't make `int`, `string`, etc implement `ISomething`

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I guess moving from ArrayList to List<> is the way to go.

Comment: @StefanS that is just one option; it can work either way - but heterogeneous data is always a pain. I'm happy to advise further if you have a concrete example...